# Optimizing regex that only matchs full urls that don't have a query string

Tags: regex, optimization

I need to optimize to following regex:

```
^(?:ht|f)tps?://[^\s]+/[^\s]+\.([^\?]+)?([\?]+$|$)
```

It searches for urls that start with http(s) or ftp(s) and contain a path and a period. if the char "?" exists (may appear multiple times) the URL must end with it, if there's any char that is not a "?" after the "?" the string will not match (e.g. a query string).

Examples:

- http://www.example.com/page.html - will match
- http://www.example.com/page/nothing - will not match
- http://www.example.com/page/nothing.html? - will match
- http://www.example.com/page/nothing.html?a=anything - will not match
- http://www.example.com/page/nothing.html????? will match

My regex works fine for *normal* urls, but in the following case:

```
http://u.example.something.com/abc=aaadddrBccc2SgFV000ALK2Qddd_;_vvv=Yu3DUzBHNlzcHIEY29sYMTEzZHQ5NjUzBHNlY9sbwNiZjEEdnRpZANRMU0wMV8xBHBvcwMx/CC=20/RE=MU0wMV8xBHBvcwMx/UU=10/ZZ=http://hhh.w.example.com/?uv=xxxxxx878787xxxxxxxxjhkjhkjhjkhADFADFS-&u=http://wwww.example.com/%2fuuu-lllllll%2sdfg-afd-adsfadf%2asdfaf000%3asdfasdfasfd%3dbing%26uasdfadf%3dcpc%26asdfadf%3d_ASDF234_ASDF%26asdfasF_asdfasdf%3d%252Bfasdfadsf%2520%252Basdf%2520%252Bdesign%26asdfasdf_aasdf%3dlf9McvAV%7cFADF%7c4063555565%7cpkw%7c%252Bfree%2520%252Bpcb%2520%252Basdf%7casdf%7asdf%7adf%7adf%7c/PO=0/UJ=iasdf7PASDFASDF-?p=this+is+an+example;
```

the reqex engine will walk ~45K steps to finally decide that the url doesn't suppose to match which is very inefficient.

Comment: You don't need a character class for the one question mark.  `[\?]+` is the same as `\?+`.

Comment: Want to optimize ? search if there's more than one `?` before using regex ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually tweak your regex to use a **negation based pattern** and dramatically improve the regex performance. Use this regex:

```
^(?:ht|f)tps?://[^/]+/[^.]+\.([^?]+)\?*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF3bF2/1)

Instead of **25k+ steps in regex debugger now it takes only 62 steps** to reject this URL which is not a match.